# Can I build an array using a loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I just started learning Ruby/Rails, and am trying to write a program that builds an array, then formats the new array.

It works up to the second `while`, and, if I have an array already built, the second part works as well.  Is there something I am leaving out?

```
chap = []
page = []
lineWidth = 80
x = 0
n = chap.length.to_i
puts 'chapter?'
chapter = gets.chomp
while chapter != ''
  chap.push chapter
  puts 'page?'
  pg = gets.chomp
  page.push pg
  puts 'chapter?'
  chapter = gets.chomp
end
puts ('Table of Contents').center lineWidth
puts ''
while x < n
 puts ('Chapter ' + (x+1).to_s + ' ' + chap[x]).ljust(lineWidth/2) +(' page ' + page[x]).rjust(lineWidth/2)
 x = x + 1
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the length `n` is calculated before actually building the chap array, therefore x == n == 0. Move `n=chap.length.to_i` to after the first while. Also you don't need to_i

Comment: As a note on style, `chapter != ''` is not very pretty. Better is something like `!chapter.empty?` where you're testing `chapter` itself, not doing a comparison against another string. `x += 1` is also preferable to `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple pilot error:  You called

```
n = chap.length.to_i
```

too early.   You have to get the length of the chap list AFTER you put things in it.  Move that line here:

```
    ...
    puts 'chapter?'
    chapter = gets.chomp
end
n = chap.length.to_i

puts ('Table of Contents').center lineWidth
```

and it works fine.